# 405 Error with POST request (AngularJS $http)

Tags: angularjs, http, google-api, google-contacts-api

I want to do a post request on Google Contacts API with AngularJS $http.

I tried to do this :

```html
var config = {
    headers: {
        // "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token,
        "GData-Version": "3.0"
    }
}

var data = {
    "test": "test"
}

$http.post('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/', data, config);
```

But it returns "*XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405*"

This request is working (returns 201 created) on a RestClient like Postman.

If someone could explain to me why this method is not allowed from a browser.

Comment: `$http.get` that's not a post request...

Comment: My bad, I'm using post ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts` API simply doesn't support `OPTIONS` requests. The `405` response is essentially saying the endpoint doesn't support the `OPTIONS` request, not necessarily that it doesn't support `POST`.

The solution is to use Google's own [JavaScript API library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) rather than Angular's `$http` service.

> You can use the JavaScript client library to interact with Google APIs, such as People, Calendar, and Drive, from your web applications.

There's also [some documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors) on how Google's API library supports CORS requests.

There may be some Angular wrapped versions of this library to make your life a little easier however I haven't dug around.

Comment: I will check this way, thanks for your help !
Is it possible to call gapi.client.request() for a Post req ?