# Delete contacts using Google Contacts API with JS/jQuery

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to delete Google contacts using their customer ID as mentioned in Google Contacts API version 3.0. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#deleting_contacts

Here is the code after authentication:

```
    $.ajax({
    url:"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{emailid}/full/{usercontactId}?access_token=" + token.access_token,
        headers: {
             "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'If-Match': '*',
            'Gdata-version': '3.0'
        },
         dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {},
        success: function (output) {
            console.log(output)
        }

    });
```

I have given the correct "access_token", "emailID" and "usercontactId".

Please let me know the issue in the above code.

Comment: are you setting the HTTP method to DELETE? This looks like a GET request.

Comment: Yes, I have added in the above code "method : 'DELETE'". Like the following one. "$.ajax({method : 'DELETE',url:"https://www.google.com....." but I got only the details of the particular contact. I think my code is wrong. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `DELETE` HTTP method to execute this.

The *access_token* should be in `headers` of your request.

Your URL should contain:

**URL**: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/{contactID}

**Headers**: `"GData-Version": "3.0", "Authorization":"Bearer " + token.accesstoken, "if-match":"*"`

You don't need to pass data to a delete request, or even content-type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I got this error.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/xxxxxxxx. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405. 

Please let me know the issue.

Comment: How are you calling your request ?

Comment: Here is the code I have used. I have checked I am using the correct accesstoken value. $.ajax({
   method : 'DELETE',
   url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/18efa588a46dd9 ",
   headers: {
    "GData-Version": "3.0",
    "Authorization":"Bearer " + token.accesstoken,
    "if-match":"*"
   },
   success: function (output) {
    console.log(output)
   }
  }); Please let me know the issue. Also in the API manager "Authorized JavaScript origins" I have added the website name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389224/405-error-with-post-request-angularjs-http

Answer (score -1):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762065/how-can-i-manage-google-accounts-contacts-through-javascript). Try to use the [google client api for javascript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client). Authenticate, getToken, use [Request](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#gapiclientrequestargs) and then execute it.

> For delete purpose, pass these as its input:
>
> ```
> method : 'DELETE',
> url : '/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/<friend id to delete>'
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry the above code is not working with mine. I will try with Google API Javascript. Thank you very much.